# How can we transfer ERC721 tokens through MetaMask and JavaScript?

Tags: django, ethereum, metamask, marketplace, erc721

We are trying to develop an NFT marketplace in a **Django project**. At this point we know how to integrate MetaMask with our project and use the JavaScript MetaMask API to send ETH transactions ('eth_sendTransaction') or check the balance of a wallet.

But we would also know how to **transfer NFT (ERC721) tokens** between wallets (allow users to buy their NFTs) with and endpoint of this JavaScript API for MetaMask. If it's possible, we would like to have the transfer of the ERC721 token and the amount of ETH payed **in the same transaction**. Like it's shown in the image below:

[Example of SepoliaETH token transfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb6qC.png)

Is there any endpoint in the link below which can help us solving this issue?
[MetaMask API](https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/how-to/)

Thank you

We tried to use scripts but we don't want to have the private keys of the users' wallets in our marketplace server because we don't have the permissions to store this kind of data.